# Cannot Launch Software Center or sudo apt-get update VER 12.04

Tags: updates

I cannot open Update Manager, Software Manager, or install a new OS or Firefox.

The `sudo apt-get update` command in terminal results in the below error. Sorry can only post two errors:

```
W: Failed to fetch http://packages.medibuntu.org/dists/precise/non-free/i18n/Translation-en_US  Something wicked happened resolving 'packages.medibuntu.org:http' (-5 - No address associated with hostname)

W: Failed to fetch http://packages.medibuntu.org/dists/precise/non-free/i18n/Translation-en  Something wicked happened resolving 'packages.medibuntu.org:http' (-5 - No address associated with hostname)

E: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
```

Answer (score 1):

Medibuntu repository has now been shut down. Package present in this repository were either obsolete, unnecessary or moved to the official Ubuntu archive.

To resolve this error

- Remove all the line containing `http://packages.medibuntu.org..`  from your `/etc/apt/sources.list` file.
- Also remove `medibuntu.list` from  `etc/apt/sources.list.d/` directory (if present) using

  ```
  sudo rm -f /etc/apt/sources.list.d/medibuntu.list
  ```
- After it execute

  ```
  sudo apt-get update
  ```

Comment: Thanks, that was a big improvement. Now I only get this error:

Comment: W: Failed to fetch http://www.geekconnection.org/remastersys/repository/karmic/Sources  404  Not Found

E: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.W: Failed to fetch http://www.geekconnection.org/remastersys/repository/karmic/Sources  404  Not Found

E: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.W: Failed to fetch http://www.geekconnection.org/remastersys/repository/karmic/Sources  404  Not Found

E: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.

Comment: Have you tried this post?http://askubuntu.com/questions/65911/how-can-i-fix-a-404-error-when-using-a-ppa-or-updating-my-package-lists